# Kiwi plant dry leaves and white spots

Tags: containers, dryness, kiwifruit

Since a long time my kiwi plants have white dots on their leaves. Now also, one of them is developing a dry spell on one of it's leaves.

Anyone know what the problem might be?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The plant doesn't seem healthy. How much do you water the kiwi? But this kind of spots seems more lack something like: lack of right fertilizer (and pH), or sunburns. A photo of the bottom side of leaves could help (pick of insects). Please add more information on question.

Comment: Ther are no insects on the bottom of the leaves. The orange spots may be sunburn but that doesn't explain the dry parts, does it? What would you recommend? The soil is mostly damp, I water it when it seems to go dry, then I let the excess water leak from the bottom.

Comment: I don't know what these spots are because I haven't grown kiwi before, but I have seen similar thin and paper-y leaves on plants that got their leaves splashed with drops of water. In the first pic, the leaf on the middle is sick because it stays close to the damp soil. The leaf in pic no.4 looks to be in contact with the rim of the pot and in case it is splashed with water, it stays wet for a while because air circulation is low there. Also, it looks like the square container keeps the soil too moist in the round one, contributing to poor health of this plant.

Comment: hmm, is this still savable or is the plant doomed? It has grown even worse at this point.

Comment: For what it's worth my kiwi plant had similar symptoms until I watered it with coffee to lower the pH and (possibly coincidentally) its growth exploded within a week so I could then safely snip off the sickly leaves.

Comment: I ended up composting the plants, they died eventually. I guess I'll try that next time, I'll be starting up some new ones soon.